# What's the benefit of OWL Import?

Tags: import, ontology, owl

I can use qualifiers by using a namespace, why do we need to import an ontology then? For example, if I've included a lexica from WordNet in my ontology, what benefits do I have of importing the WordNet ontology in my ontology? Does it help in querying using SPARQL? Any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By importing an ontology you gain access to its axioms, e.g. reasoning happens over the import-closure of the ontology.

Comment: i can't say importing whole ontology to yours as a benefit. It would cause a big reasoning problem.

Comment: What is a "big reasoning problem"? ;) The bottom line is that if you want to reason about some axioms then you have to tell the reasoner where these axioms are. Importing is a way of linking together ontologies (sets of axioms) such that the reasoner can find all of them. If you think that "whole ontology" is too big and causes a big problem, then modularize it and import only what you need...

Comment: could you clarify the steps to "then modularize it and import only what you need..." Imagine that you don't have control over that ontology that you import. What do you do. You create a light weight version of it that reassert those axioms that interest you, using the original uri of course, and then you import that ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon instead of a comment, ask a new question, this way it gets more visibility